# Imagecache Custom Actions - Imagemagick

Tags: media, actions

I cannot get my imagecache custom actions to work at all?

When returning $image in any way, it gives me an error, which can be resolved by adding in the first line here:

```
if (!$image_context['entity']) { return 'No referring entity'; }
$image->ops[0] = "-resize 1600x1600";
return $image;
```

That should simply just resize my images now?

Essentially, my end goal is to check the value of a field submitted with the node which also submitted the original image, and then based on its value, apply a watermark. I am just toying about with custom PHP right now... but I can't seem to get any custom actions to work right now... Any help would be great, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Juste return "TRUE", not "$image", It is works for me.

```
 $image->ops[] = "-resize 1600x1600";
 return TRUE;
```